# Is there a way to create searchable Area with Google Maps in Flutter (using google_maps_flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's say you want to build an app where people can find out whether the location the users are on has a risk of being flooded. You want to be able to create flood zone areas on the map and compare the user geolocation relative to the area. How do I do that with google_maps_flutter? or is there any other way to do it with plugins in flutter?

What I have in mind right now is to create polygons on the map and perform some geometric operations with it (if that is even possible). I have Esri SHP files which I will export to json and parse it in flutter and then use the results to draw polygons of the areas.

no code just yet..

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of 'overlay widgets' in Flutter. You can draw, say a circle, indicating a flood zone with colour and radius in accordance with the probability (or other parameters). 
Depending on how you want to display, you can create a separate UI control to display the comparision with reference to the user's geo-location.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/b7HQMFsF has a sample code if you would like to refer.